# "X-Content-Type-Options" header with Value "nosniff" block CSS and JS

Tags: x-content-type-options

When we use "X-Content-Type-Options" value as "nosniff". This block all CSS and JS files to render in Asp.Net Application.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: when we put <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" /> header in web.config then it block all CSS and JS in my application. So how we can resolve this issue?